# Launching Android AVD device crashes after 2 secs (mac). How to fix?

Tags: android, macos, sdk, terminal

I'm on a Mac Pro, OS version 10.5.8.

Installed android SDK, and was successfully launching and using emulators all morning.  Then this afternoon, the emulator CRASHES every single time I try to launch one.

The sequence is: select (or create a new) AVD targeting Android 2.3, Skin is set to WVGA854... click "start"... emulator device launches, shows the black screen with "Android _ " for about 1-2 seconds, then crashes.

Tried restarting the mac, deleted android SDK along with the hidden .android folder it creates, then reinstalled SDK, tried different settings on the AVD device, all lead to the same result.

Pasted below is the error log from the last crash.

Anyone know what I can do to fix??

Answer (score 0):

On the web I found these suggestions:

- Remove your USB sound while the emulator is booting.
- Pull the audio device from the USB slot, start the emulator, and re-insert the audio device after the emulator has booted.
- Assign the audio-in to the internal microphone it works.
- Use `-noaudio` (See the emulator `-help`).

Comment: Also had this problem with a Cinema Display connected via USB. Just removed the USB cable and the emulator worked again.